# Does any of the executors run on the driver node in cluster deploy mode?

Tags: apache-spark

While running a program in Cluster mode, does any executor also run on the node on which the Driver Program is running.

Following text explains about the cluster mode:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

But doesn't answer this question.

Thanks
Anuj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the cluster manger implementation, configuration and requested resources. In general cluster manager is free to start multiple containers on the same physical node.

So without additional assumptions - driver can be, but doesn't have to be, colocated with one or more executors.